# How to share a folder on Ubuntu to Raspberry Pi 3 over local WiFi network?

Tags: networking, shared-folders, raspberrypi

I am planing to buy RaspberryPi 3 and have it connected to my TV. I also have a lot of movies on Windows partition in my dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 & Win 8 machine (Win 8 isn't used, but is there). I would like to share the movies folder to RaspberryPi over my WiFi, so that I can watch movies on TV without loading the movie file to RaspberryPi.

Can this be done and how?

Comment: If you use the Kodi image for raspberry pi, you get inbuilt support for NFS and Samba. Then all you need to do is setup the service on your server as the other answers describe.

Comment: I use webdav to stream over http protocol. In this case the media player is aware that it is using a network resource and it can properly configure settings like buffering. I had some bad experience with network filesystems as an application trying to cache a multi-GB file can freeze a system (and the whole local network) for several minutes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

my favourite method is via SSHFS.

1. Install openssh server on your Ubuntu machine: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`
2. Install sshfs on the Raspberry Pi (don't know the package name for the distro you're running), in Ubuntu:`sudo apt-get install sshfs`
3. Connect to your ssh server by mounting a folder:`sshfs username_on_server@server_ip:/location_of/movies_on_Server  /mountpoint/on_rasberry_pi`
4. You might have to add your Rasberry Pi user to the fuser group: `sudo useradd -G {group-name} username`
5. to unmount the remote folder: `fusermount -u /mountpoint/on_rasberry_pi`

Enjoy.

Comment: Until step 3 all was good, but on 4 what `fuser` group is that? And on 5 I had the error `fusermount: entry for /mnt/backup not found in /etc/mtab` (being /mnt/backup my mount point on raspberry pi)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the above, you could use samba shares.
Instructions are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!).

This is definitely supported by [KODI](https://kodi.tv/about/) ([openELEC](http://openelec.tv/home/what-is-openelec), [Osmc](https://osmc.tv/about/) or other), which is what I would install on the raspberry pi, if you want to use it as a media player for the TV, and resembles my setup.

(Though I think kodi also sees NFS)

Here is a summary of the instructions (credit goes to the original author):

Procedures

### Install Samba

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install samba
```

### Set a password for your user in Samba

```
    sudo smbpasswd -a <user_name>
```

Note: Samba uses a separate set of passwords than the standard Linux system accounts (stored in /etc/samba/smbpasswd), so you'll need to create a Samba password for yourself. This tutorial implies that you will use your own user and it does not cover situations involving other users passwords, groups, etc...

**Tip 1:** Use the password for your own user to facilitate.

**Tip 2:** Remember that your user must have permission to write and edit the folder you want to share.

```
        Eg.:
        sudo chown <user_name> /var/opt/blah/blahblah
        sudo chown :<user_name> /var/opt/blah/blahblah
```

**Tip3:** If you're using another user than your own, it needs to exist in your system beforehand, you can create it without a shell access using the following command :
            sudo useradd USERNAME --shell /bin/false

You can also hide the user on the login screen by adjusting lightdm's configuration, in /etc/lightdm/users.conf add the newly created user to the line :

```
        hidden-users=
```

### Create a directory to be shared

```
mkdir /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
```

Make a safe backup copy of the original smb.conf file to your home folder, in case you make an error

```
sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf ~

Edit the file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Once "smb.conf" has loaded, add this to the very end of the file:

```
    [<folder_name>]
    path = /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
    valid users = <user_name>
    read only = no
```

**Tip:** There Should be in the spaces between the lines, and also there should be a single space both before and after each of the equal signs.

### Restart samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Once Samba has restarted, use this command to check your smb.conf for any syntax errors

```
testparm
```

### To access your network share

```
  sudo apt-get install smbclient
  # List all shares:
  smbclient -L //<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>/<folder_name> -U <user>
  # connect:
  smbclient //<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>/<folder_name> -U <user>
```

To access your network share use your username () and password through the path "smb:////" (Linux users) or "\\\" (Windows users). Note that "" value is passed in "[]", in other words, the share name you entered in "/etc/samba/smb.conf".

```
    Note: The default user group of samba is "WORKGROUP".
```

Comment: Instructional pages are great. Broken links are not. It would be more helpful if you were to edit your answer to include a detailed summary of the steps included on that link. That way, your answer will still be helpful even if something happens to that link.

Comment: @TheBrownOne Modified my answer accordingly (though I think that the universality of that rule should be discussed)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).

This is useful to read about: [How do I mount directories from other Linux/Unix/BSD servers? How do I mount an NFS share?](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#How_do_I_mount_directories_from_other_Linux.2FUnix.2FBSD_servers.3F__How_do_I_mount_an_NFS_share.3F)

How to setup NFS in Ubuntu: [SettingUpNFSHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)

### Ubuntu NFS Server Configuration

Below example shares **Public** directory (located in **pba** user home directory) to **10.0.0.1** IP address

Install NFS Server

```
sudo apt-get install rpcbind nfs-kernel-server
```

Make sharing directory and set permissions

```
mkdir -p ~/Public
chmod 777 ~/Public
```

Add new share to /etc/exports

```
echo "/home/pba/Public 10.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)" | sudo tee -a /etc/exports
```

rw makes the share read/write, and sync requires the server to only reply to requests once any changes have been flushed to disk. This is the safest option (async is faster, but dangerous. It is strongly recommended that you read man exports.

Export new share

```
sudo exportfs -ra
```

Restart NFS kernel server

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Server is now ready.

### Raspberry Pi Client Side Configuration

In below example **10.0.0.12** is a NFS server IP address with **/home/pba/Public** share

Install NFS, portmap and start services

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common portmap
sudo service rpcbind start
sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable
```

Make mount directory and mount NFS

```
mkdir ~/Public
sudo mount -v -t nfs 10.0.0.12:/home/pba/Public /home/pi/Public
```

Seeing results:

```
$ cd ~/Public && ls
Ubuntu file  Ubuntu file~
```

Add line to /etc/fstab to make changes permanent

```
echo "10.0.0.12:/home/pba/Public /home/pi/Public nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

### For Windows

I've download [FreeNFS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freenfs/) for Windows. FreeNFS path set to `C:\Public`.

To mount FreeNFS share mount need to be done like this

```
sudo mount -v -t nfs 10.0.0.12:/ /home/pi/Public
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted? This is about sharing from ***Windows*** to an RPi.

Comment: Windows part is how I did it with windows machine to test NFS with RPi, including info how to set it up with `any` machine on RPi. I will add to my answer link to Ubuntu NFS help page... Downvote not appreciated.

Comment: Instead of linking to a help-page, it would be *helpful* if you were to explain how to use NFS on Ubuntu. Then I will reverse my downvote. As it stands, this answer does not provide a solution for setting up a share from Ubuntu. Simply providing a link would make it no more than a "link only answer", which is discouraged.

Comment: Right, I did improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across one more option to do this: http://zhenga.net/

Seems a bit wary in comparison to SSH or Samba, but it definitely looks promising. I have set it up for file/movie/photo sharing between the LibreELEC Pi and my notebooks running Windows and MacOS and it works like a charm.

They claim to be secure and boast connectivity over the Internet. I tried this once and it switched from LAN to WAN addresses and back seamlessly, depending on the network availability, which is *very* convenient. Though I can't say proprietary solution is a best option to use ouside your home LAN