# Virtualbox android virtual machine how to access the folder on the host machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, android, shared-folders

I have installed an android virtual machine in Virtualbox on my Ubuntu 16.04 host machine.

And I have set the `Network` as `Host-only Adapter`.
[image: android virtual machine network]

And here it is the shared folder:[image: shared folder]
I can't access the shared folder in android virtual machine.

And I the IP address of the android virtual machine is `192.168.56.101`. And `adb connect 192.168.56.101` has successfully connected.
I have tried `ES file explorer`, but I don't how it can access the shared folder in my host machine.

So I want to know how I can access the host machine folders in android virutal machine. Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: Have you shared any folders?

Comment: OK, I have share the `/tmp/test` folder, but in android virtual machine, I can't access it.@Bruni

Comment: Have you tried ES File explorer or Amaze on the android client?

Comment: I have tried ES file explorer, but in the `LAN` menu, I can't find a server. @Bruni.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an android VM to check right now...an admittedly overkill alternative would be to install a samba server on the host, but maybe just wait for someone better qualified than me to solve this. You should also include in your question that you have installed the guest additions on the client as else sharing folders will not work.

Comment: @Bruni, there is no *guest add-ons* for android virtual machine. So i don't how to do this?

Comment: If you want to go the samba way, here https://askubuntu.com/questions/777717/how-to-share-a-folder-on-ubuntu-to-raspberry-pi-3-over-local-wifi-network/777768#777768 are some instructions

Comment: Thank you, you means that I can set up a samba server, and access the samba server on the android machine. Right? @Bruni

Comment: Exactly, that is what I do to share files between my android phone and Ubuntu.